# Calendar control date not known (ASP.Net)

Tags: sql, asp.net

Sometimes we have dates that are unknown, eg: We won't know the date but just the month and year.

eg: --/Dec/2015, the date is not known? How do we accept these kind of values?

Any ideas on can this be stored on SQL Server database?

Comment: You can store it as `2015-12-01` datetime/date. If you need to differentiate between those with date and those without you could use another bit-column `IsDateKnown`.

Answer (score 1):

I would store it as a date in the database. Because with a date you have benefits like:

- Calculation function like `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`.
- You will be able to sort on one column
- Index will be one column
- When you need to get the year and the month. You just use `MONTH` and `YEAR`